# Google Maps React stuck in 'loading map...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

I created a component called MapContainer and my MapContainer.js looks like this:

```
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import React from 'react';
import '../css/MapContainer.css';

const MapContainer = ({ t }) => (
    <Map class="location_map"
    google={t.google}
    zoom={8}
    initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}/>
)

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: '...'
})(MapContainer);
```

Then I import this component into another .js called Details.js.
File's very long so I only put the parts related to the MapContainer.

```
import MapContainer from '../components/MapContainer';
```

...

Then inside the render part:

```
            <div class="polaroid_des">
                <div class="container-list">
                    <p class="polaroid_title">{t('details.location')}</p>
                    <MapContainer t={t} />
                </div>
            </div>
```

And I end up exporting it as:

```
export default withTranslation()(Details);
```

Turns out I only get 'Loading map...' when I run my site. What's happening?

Comment: @kinduser if u want you can answer that and I'll accept your answer. I switched to react-google-maps and I made it work. I also had to enable billing form GCP.

Comment: Sure, I have added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem like 2 days ago. This library is out-of-date and not maintained anymore. I'd suggest you to use `google-map-react` instead. I found that library much more solid.

Github: https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#sample-usage-with-lazy-loading-google-api), the `google` instance has to be grabbed from the decorated component props.

```
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import React from 'react';
import '../css/MapContainer.css';

const MapContainer = ({ t, google }) => (
    <Map class="location_map"
    google={google}
    zoom={8}
    initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}/>
)

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: '...'
})(MapContainer);
```